# How to cut a row from a protected Table in one worksheet and paste into next available row in a table on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet containing a protected table.  I have worked out (through sites such as this) how to add a row to the bottom of the table through VBA.  What I would also like to do is cut a specific row from the protected table and paste into the next available row on an identical table (either protected or unprotected, doesn't matter) in another worksheet.

For clarity it is a multi-stage tracker and once the end of the journey has been reached the row being cut is being archived.

Grateful for any assistance available

For reference, this is the code I have for adding a row which works seamlessly (if I don't hide all the unused rows for a neater table):

```
    Sub Button15_Click()
    Dim xRg, tableRg As Range
        Dim xRowCount As Integer
        Dim pswStr As String
        pswStr = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=pswStr

        Set tableRg = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range
        xRowCount = tableRg.Rows.Count

        Set xRg = Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Reason if surgery not carried out or unsuccessful]]").Offset(1, 0)
        Set yRg = xRg.Resize(xRowCount, 1)
        xRg.Resize(xRowCount - 1, 1).AutoFill Destination:=yRg, Type:=xlFillDefault

        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=pswStr, DrawingObjects:=False, _
                Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False, _
                AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
                AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=True, _
                AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, _
                AllowDeletingColumns:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, _
                AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
                AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

I have attempted to write something for this using the code for adding a row, a simplistic macro recording (for cutting and pasting) and further research on the web and come up with the below.  What I am trying to write is something that will look at the values in cells within column "AM" if they equal "Yes" then cut that row, paste into a new identical spreadsheet, then delete the original row.  Ultimately this could mean more than one row at a time but if simpler then one row at a time is fine.

Unfortunately when I run the code it comes up with an error "Compile error: Block If without End If".  I absolutely know I will have gone wrong but a pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Sub Macro3()

```
Dim xRg, tableRg As Range
Dim xRowCount As Integer
Dim pswStr As String
pswStr = ""
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=pswStr

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AM:AM")) Is Nothing Then
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Sheets("HD Archive").Cells(Rows.Count, "AM").End(x1Up).Row + 1

If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
Rows(Target.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("HD Archive").Rows(Lastrow)
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Rows(Target.Row).Delete
     
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=pswStr, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows _
    :=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables _
    :=True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Did you try writing any code to move the row?  If Yes what specific problems did you run into?

Comment: @TimWilliams I haven't written any code yet.  Whilst I understand the premise of VBA and the ability to use it I am no where near skilled enough to write code unfortunately.